Multi containers communication deployment AWS Lightsail
I am developing a project using php on my client side and node.js on my server side. I used docker compose to create one container for each side and I managed to make it work perfectly on my local machine. However, when I try to deploy them under the same service and using "service://localhost" as a enviroment variable I get the "took too long" and "port 80 is not healthy" errors. I'm using port 80 to my client side and port 8000 to my server side. I am new to this and read all the documentation but still am struggling to understand how to do this correctly. I'd appreciate any kind of help!
I tried changing ports, changing the health check path and the timeout seconds but the deployments still fail.
